# SQL Attempting to use variables to provide a log

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am using MS SQL and I am attempting to setup my statements such that I can easily have a log printed as the code is executed. For some reason my variables appear to be out of scope and I can't determine why.

Error received: `Must declare the scalar variable "@Ideas"`

Snippet of what works (aka without attempting to print out):

```
DECLARE @Ideas TABLE(IdeaID int) 
INSERT INTO @Ideas (IdeaID) 
    SELECT IdeaID FROM dbo.Ideas 
    WHERE IdeaID IN (5,6,7) 
DELETE FROM dbo.TableA WHERE IdeaID IN (SELECT IdeaID FROM @Ideas)
DELETE FROM dbo.TableB WHERE IdeaID IN (SELECT IdeaID FROM @Ideas)
DELETE FROM dbo.TableC WHERE IdeaID IN (SELECT IdeaID FROM @Ideas)
```

And the deletes continue after that from various tables but always the same array of IDs... my attempt to provide a way of printing the transactions:

```
DECLARE @PopulateIdeas varchar(500)
DECLARE @Ideas TABLE(IdeaID int)
SET @PopulateIdeas = 
    '
    INSERT INTO' + @Ideas + '(IdeaID) 
    SELECT [IdeaID] 
    FROM [dbo].[Ideas]
    WHERE [IdeaID] IN (5,6,7,8) 
    '
PRINT @PopulateIdeas
EXECUTE (@PopulateIdeas)
```

At this point I haven't even attempted to setup the deletes because I am stuck at populating my temp table and having it print... All help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You are running dynamic sql through an implied call to `sp_executesql`. This runs in a separate batch to where the query is constructed so has no knowledge of your local variable. Read up on [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for how to pass variables into scope.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, you can only pass a table variable to `sp_executesql` as `READONLY`, so you cannot accomplish what you are intending in this method. Maybe a global temporary table is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone else has said, this is a scoping issue. One work-around is to use "#temp" tables, as follows. It is not an ideal solution, particularly if there is a lot of data involved, but for small sets it should be fine.

```
DECLARE @PopulateIdeas varchar(500)

CREATE TABLE #Ideas (IdeaID int)

SET @PopulateIdeas = 
    '
    INSERT INTO #Ideas (IdeaID) 
    SELECT IdeaID
    FROM dbo.Ideas
    WHERE IdeaID IN (5,6,7,8) 
    '

PRINT @PopulateIdeas
EXECUTE (@PopulateIdeas)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is the scope of your local variable `@ideas` because the execute is calling the function `sp_executesql`

To fix this you have to move the declare statement inside the string.

This is **not** a good pattern but to do it you can just change your code to be:

```
DECLARE @PopulateIdeas varchar(500)

SET @PopulateIdeas = 
    'DECLARE @Ideas TABLE(IdeaID int);

    INSERT INTO @Ideas(IdeaID) 
    SELECT [IdeaID] 
    FROM [dbo].[Ideas]
    WHERE [IdeaID] IN (5,6,7,8) 
    '
PRINT @PopulateIdeas
EXECUTE (@PopulateIdeas)
```